# How upload a laravel project on a web hosting?

Tags: laravel, hosting, vps

I'm new in Laravel. I want to create a laravel project but I don't know how to upload the project in my web hosting, Do I need a VPS? or with my web hosting can shared on internet?

VPS is more expensive than Web hosting, and I just have web hosting and obviously I want to upload it there.

Comment: If you're new to Laravel and web hosting using a framework, you should try Laravel Forge. It will help you deploy to a VPS of your choice on AWS, Digital Ocean, or other quick-deploy options.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty easy.

You basically need to split your project files into two different folders before uploading.

Steps to take:

1. All laravel project files inside your `public` folder should be moved to your `public_html` folder on your server.
2. On your server, create a new folder e.g `my_app` on the same directory level as `public_html` and move the rest of your laravel project to that.
3. Go to your `public_html/index.php` and edit the `require` and `require_once` lines to match your directory structure. 
   In your case, that would be:

From `__DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';` to `__DIR__.'/../my_app/bootstrap/autoload.php';`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to keep the structure as it is and upload a .htaccess file at the root.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On 
   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
   RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

on my case for laravel 6 its working parfectly!